# Awaiting a reflected method where the return type is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, async-await, task, reflections

I have a bunch of classes that include an async method `ExecuteAsync()`.

These classes return different types.

I need to invoke the `ExecuteAsync()` method by reflection.

I know, from many other questions on SO, that if I knew the return type, I could just write, for example:

```cs
var task (Task<int>) obj.GetType().GetMethod("ExecuteAsync").Invoke(obj, null);
var result = await task;
```

I've got to the point where I can do this to get the task...

```cs
    var method = p.GetType().GetMethod("ExecuteAsync");
    var rt = method.ReturnType.Dump();
    var task = Convert.ChangeType(method!.Invoke(p, null)!, rt);
```

but then `var result = await task` won't compile as the compiler thinks `task` is of type `object?` and "object? is not awaitable".

Is there a way of executing/awaiting `task`?

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried casting `task` to `Task<object?>`? Either that or using `dynamic`

Comment: @DejanJanjušević `Task<T>` does not support variance over `T`, so you cannot cast a `Task<String>` to `Task<Object>`.

Comment: Yes, if I do that with a reference type as the return - `Task<SomeClass>` it compiles but crashes at runtime.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` <-- This method does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Just return `Task` and get your result with reflection.

Comment: @shingo I'm not sure I follow. do you mean `var task = (Task)method.Invoke(...)`? That will work but I can't then say `var result = await task` 'cos the compiler won't allow the assignment to an implicitly typed variable, so I'm back where I started

Comment: @StuartHemming If you don't know what `result`'s type is, how do you intend to use it?

Comment: Await the task without fetching the result, get the result from this `task` variable with reflection (Task<T> has a Result property).

Comment: `Task<T>` inherits from `Task` so just cast to that and await it. How you deal with `task.Result` is then up to you (and more reflection)

Comment: In short, these classes have "side effects" and the result they return reports on the success/failure and nature of those side effect and that is used when the methods are executed in other bits of the system (via the UI for example). However, there is a requirement to also run these methods via a background service, and that's what's happening here

Comment: Where is the method defined that returns the Task? Instead of using `Task<T>`, can't you return `Task<object>` instead and await that? Once it's done, you could cast the result to your desired Target type, if you know what the Type will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start to use reflection you tend to need to continue using reflection. You should be able to cast your result to a `Task` and await this. But to get the actual result you probably need to use reflection to access the `Task.Result` property. So I would try something like this:

```
var resultTask = obj.GetType().GetMethod("ExecuteAsync").Invoke(obj, null);
await (Task)resultTask ;
var result = (int)resultTask.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(resultTask, null);
```

But I would only use solutions like this as the last resort, or for very quick and dirty code. In most cases other patterns can be used, and should be easier to maintain than using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

- Ultimately your problem is getting the `.Result` of a `Task<T>` from a `T`-which-we-don't-know to a *boxed* value (i.e. as an `Object` reference).
- One option is to use a *normal* generic method to `await` the *real* `Task`, and return the result as an `Object?`.

  - ...and to invoke that "normal" generic method via `MakeGenericMethod` which allows you to specify generic type arguments at runtime using reflection.

Like so:

- `Utility.InvokeAndAwaitReflectedMethodImplAsync` is the generic method which is instantiated as a *closed* generic method using `MakeGenericMethod` using type-arguments derived from `MethodInfo`.
- `class Mystery`'s `DoSomethingAsync` method is being invoked using reflection, without any part of the program being-aware (at compile-time) that `DoSomethingAsync` returns `Task<Int32>`.

```
class Mystery
{
    private readonly Random rng = new Random();
    
    public async Task<Int32> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay( 1000 );
        
        return this.rng.Next();
    }
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    Object mysteryObject = new Mystery();

    Type typeOfMystery = mysteryObject.GetType();

    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeOfMystery.GetMethod( "DoSomethingAsync" );
    
    //

    Object? result = await Utility.InvokeAndAwaitReflectedMethodAsync( mysteryObject, methodInfo, Array.Empty<Object?>() );
   
    Console.WriteLine( "Result: {0}", result );
}

public static class Utility
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _invokeAndAwaitMethodInfo = typeof(Utility).GetMethod( name: nameof(InvokeAndAwaitReflectedMethodImplAsync), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static )!;

    public static async Task<Object?> InvokeAndAwaitReflectedMethodAsync( Object obj, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object?[] args )
    {
        Type methodTaskInnerType = methodInfo.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // Assuming `methodInfo.ReturnType == Task<T>`, then `methodTaskInnerType == T`.
        
        //
        
        MethodInfo invokerGen = _invokeAndAwaitMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod (/*TObject:*/ obj.GetType(), /*TReturn:*/ methodTaskInnerType );

        Object[] argsForInvokeAndAwait = new Object[] { /*obj:*/ obj, /*methodInfo:*/ methodInfo, /*args:*/ args };

        Task<Object?> asTaskObj = (Task<Object?>)invokerGen.Invoke( obj: null, parameters: argsForInvokeAndAwait )!;

        Object? result = await asTaskObj;
        return result;
    }
    
    private static async Task<Object?> InvokeAndAwaitReflectedMethodImplAsync<TObject,TReturn>( TObject obj, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object?[] args )
    {
        Type typeOfTaskOfT = typeof(Task<TReturn>);
        if( methodInfo.ReturnType != typeOfTaskOfT )
        {
            String msg = "ReturnType does not match T. Expected: " + typeOfTaskOfT.FullName + ", Actual: " + methodInfo.ReturnType.FullName;
            throw new ArgumentException( message: msg, paramName: nameof(methodInfo) );
        }

        Object? taskObj = methodInfo.Invoke( obj: obj, parameters: args );
        if( taskObj is null )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Method returned null. Expected Task." );
        }
        else if( taskObj is Task<TReturn> task )
        {
            TReturn value = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            Object? valueAsObject = value;
            return valueAsObject;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unexpected return value." );
        }
    }
}
```

---

Screenshot proof in Linqpad:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**dynamic** is often abused, but it can be used here:

```cs
dynamic dyn = obj;
var result = (int)(await dyn.ExecuteAsync());
```

```cs
dynamic dyn = obj;
Task<int> task = dyn.ExecuteAsync();
var result = await task;
```